# Which mini external speaker has louder output?

Tags: speakers

For a hobby project on Raspberry Pi3 I have two options for Speakers

- [sparkfun speaker](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14023)
- [adafruit speaker](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3369)

Which one will be louder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sparkfun will be more louder as it can provide you with about 85dbA